# Sistema de amizades

Tags: php, sql

Estou fazendo um sistema de amizades (olhe a img)

Em usuarios mostra todas as pessoas que posso add como amigos, quero remover da lista de usuarios todas as pessoas que ja me enviaram solicitação de amizade é todas as pessoas para quem eu enviei solicitação de amizade.

Estou confuso com o banco de dados com isso!
Neste exemplo abaixo se eu entrasse com o usuario numero 1 (jose) so deveria me aparecer (3) girafao porque o (2) gato já e meu amigo

É se eu entrasse com o usuario (2) gato na tabela de usuarios não deveria aparecer ninguem, porque o (1) jose já  e meu amigo e o (3) girafao eu ja enviei solicitação de amizade então nao tem necessidade de aparecer.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Só uma dica: Organiza essa tabela, trabalhe com ID secundário sem ser o auto increment, não esqueça de usar indexes, a lógica é: crie um campo chamado isFriend (int) se for 0 = não amigo se for 1 = amigo, se tiver como um esconde o botão de criar amizade e mostre o de desfazer amizade.

Comment: estado e justamente 0 nao amigo 1 amigo, mas isso nao adianta nao posso me orientar pelo estado porque somente quando a amizade e aceita que o estado vira 1.  obg pelas dicas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considere a seguinte estrutura de tabelas:

```
create table usuario (
  id int primary key auto_increment,
  nome varchar(50),
  email varchar(50),
  senha varchar(50)
);

create table relacionamento (
  de int not null,
  para int not null,
  estado boolean,
  primary key (de, para),
  foreign key (de) references usuario(id),
  foreign key (para) references usuario(id)
);
```

São basicamente iguais as suas, exceto pelo fato de o nome de alguns campos estarem um pouco diferente, e na tabela relacionamento, não haver uma chave primaria auto incremento (acho que fica melhor os campos `de` e `para` cumprirem essa função em conjunto).

Então inserindo os dados que você mostrou na pergunta:

```
insert into usuario (nome, email, senha) 
values ('jose', 'email', 'senha'), ('gato', 'email', 'senha'),
('girafão', 'email', 'senha');

insert into relacionamento (de, para, estado) values (1, 2, true), (2, 3, false);
```

Para resolver seu problema basta usar a seguinte consulta sql:

```
select * from usuario WHERE usuario.id NOT IN (SELECT de FROM
relacionamento where para = ID_USUARIO_ENTROU)
AND usuario.id NOT IN (SELECT relacionamento.para 
FROM relacionamento where relacionamento.de = ID_USUARIO_ENTROU) 
AND usuario.id != ID_USUARIO_ENTROU;
```

Basicamente são retornados todos os registros da tabela `usuario`, exceto os que são diferentes do campo de e para da tabela relacionamento, quando o de ou o para forem iguais ao usuario que entrou. E claro se o id do usuario for diferente do usuario que entrou.

As consultas a seguir demonstram a seguinte afirmação:

> Estou confuso com o banco de dados com isso! Neste exemplo abaixo se
>   eu entrasse com o usuario numero 1 (jose) so deveria me aparecer (3)
>   girafao porque o (2) gato já e meu amigo

```
select * from usuario WHERE usuario.id NOT IN (SELECT de 
FROM relacionamento where para = 1)
AND usuario.id NOT IN (SELECT relacionamento.para 
FROM relacionamento where relacionamento.de = 1) 
AND usuario.id != 1;
```

Gera como saida:

```
+---+----------+------+-------+
|id |   nome  | email | senha |
+-----------------------------+
|3  | girafão | email | senha |
+---+---------+-------+-------+
```

> É se eu entrasse com o usuario (2) gato na tabela de usuarios não
>   deveria aparecer ninguem, porque o (1) jose já e meu amigo e o (3)
>   girafao eu ja enviei solicitação de amizade então nao tem necessidade
>   de aparecer.

```
select * from usuario WHERE usuario.id NOT IN (SELECT de 
FROM relacionamento where para = 2)
AND usuario.id NOT IN (SELECT relacionamento.para 
FROM relacionamento where relacionamento.de = 2) 
AND usuario.id != 2;
```

Gera como saida:

```
+---+----------+------+-------+
|id |   nome  | email | senha |
+-----------------------------+
|   |         |       |       |
+---+---------+-------+-------+
```

E se você entrar com o usuario 3:

```
select * from usuario WHERE usuario.id NOT IN (SELECT de 
FROM relacionamento where para = 3)
AND usuario.id NOT IN (SELECT relacionamento.para 
FROM relacionamento where relacionamento.de = 3) 
AND usuario.id != 3;
```

Gera como saida:

```
+---+----------+------+-------+
|id |   nome  | email | senha |
+-----------------------------+
|1  | jose    | email | senha |
+---+---------+-------+-------+
```

Basicamente os três exemplos usam [subqueries](https://www.w3resource.com/sql/subqueries/understanding-sql-subqueries.php). Você pode testar no [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/73c596/9/0)